# Does the expression "should be introduced" affect future acts only?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does the expression "should be introduced" affect future acts only?

If a new law states that "no excise tax should be introduced in tax law", does that affect excise tax already in the regulation?

Comment: Please provide the source of the quote.  Your question is rather unclear.  I've copied the question to the body, but I don't understand what you are asking.  Please provide more details.

Comment: You should ask at https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is not a legal question at all. Of course, it would have to be in the future if the law does not at present contain something....